# How can I fix Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UIColor'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uicolor

I'm a newbie and I'm working through a tutorial on SpriteKit but running into an error. Xcode 7 doesn't like me setting color to 'nil' in the call to super.init:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Card : SKSpriteNode {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
  }

init(imageNamed: String) {
    let cardTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed)
    super.init(texture: cardTexture, color: nil, size: cardTexture.size())
  }
}
```

The that's code right from the tutorial so it must have worked at some point but I'm using Swift 2.0 and I'm guessing something's changed. It expects a UIColor object so naturally I tried one:

```
super.init(texture: cardTexture, color: whiteColor(), size: cardTexture.size())
```

but that just gives me a 'Use of unresolved identifier whiteColor' error.

How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `UIColor.whiteColor()`.  You might be able to pass just `.whiteColor()`, but the leading dot is necessary.

Comment: you need to use the UIColor initialiser UIColor.whiteColor()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For solving of the problem you should change manner you are using `whiteColor()`.

```
init(imageNamed: String) {
        let cardTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed)
        super.init(texture: cardTexture, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: cardTexture.size())
    }
```